# New Vegetable Gardener - Planning Ahead

Tags: vegetables

So this year I started two 4'x 6' (~1.2m x 1.8m) raised garden beds and am growing lots of vegetables there as well as in a handful of containers.

My question is what are the things I should do to prepare for next Spring /next full growing season. I'm in zone 5 - southern Ontario.

Should I be saving the dead plants (once I remove them). Starting a compost pile? Saving yard trimmings or raked leaves? Do I put anything over/on/in the beds once the first frost comes?  What are your pro-tips and tricks?

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a number of things you could do. You could start a compost pile if you believe you will have a need for compost next season. In general, my best tip would be once the season is over save off a few of your organic food scraps. Go out to your bed and dig a few troughs and dump you scraps inside them. Then bury the troughs and allow all those food scraps to decompose over winter. I think  you will find that your plants do very well next season. You could also go buy some earth worms and toss them in with the trash to help with the decomposition.